# What is BlockApps and how can it be used with Ethereum?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, dapp-development

[BlockApps](http://blockapps.net) says:

> Customized, permissioned private Blockchain ledger to your
>   specifications. Based on Turing-complete Ethereum standards, your
>   Blockchain has full Smart Contract support built-in.

How can BlockApps be used with Ethereum?  How can these customized, private blockchains be used with Ethereum?  How can contracts in a private BlockApps chain invoke a contract on Ethereum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPO of BlockApps here.

BlockApps exposes a REST API and Javascript and Mobile SDK to Ethereum "compliant" blockchains. This includes the public Ethereum network.

Basically you write an app with bloc [ https://github.com/blockapps/bloc ] and/or blockapps-js [ https://github.com/blockapps/blockapps-js ] and can deploy it to a developer sandbox, private / consortium network or the Ethereum livenet just by changing the API url that your app is pointed at.