# Can STRATO be utilized as an Ethereum client?

Tags: clients, microsoft-azure

Consensys [announced](https://consensys.net/static/BlockAppsonAzureMarketplace.pdf) yesterday that [BlockApps](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1254/42) STRATO is available for Microsoft Azure.

Joseph Lubin says,

> It is also a better Ethereum public mainnet node for 
>   various kinds of decentralized apps that want to write to the RESTful API instead of connecting to a node via RPC.

Does it mean STRATO offers another client implementation for Ethereum? What language is it written in? Is it even open source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STRATO uses an Ethereum client written in Haskell.

Open source https://github.com/blockapps/ethereum-vm is forked from a [repo](https://github.com/jamshidh/ethereum-vm) which says:

> This package provides a tool written in Haskell to allow you to
>   connect to the Ethereum blockchain

At the lower left of http://blockapps.net there is a link to RESTful [API Documentation](http://portal.blockapps.net/markdown).  Depending on what you need from an Ethereum client, it may work and it lists resources such as:

```
/account
/block
/transaction
/storage
```